# I keep getting errors in my procedure that help add new course and i have put requirements in description

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, error-handling

the procedure needs to ensure that:

1.The prerequisite courses for it (if any) already exist in the COURSE table. For simplicity,
we will pretend that a course can have at most one course as prerequisite.

2. The prerequisite for a course must be at a lower level. For instance, the prerequisite for `ISYS326` must be `a100-` or `200-`level course, and cannot be a `300` level course.

If either of the above requirements fails, the procedure raises an exception `WRONG_PREREQ` that prints an appropriate alert message, and does not modify the `COURSE` table.

in the procedure `CID =courseid PID=prerequisiteid and DID=deptid` they are all `not null` values

so this procedure will be used to enter new course

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW_COURSE (

CID   IN COURSE.COURSEID%TYPE,

CNAME IN COURSE.COURSENAME%TYPE,

PID   IN HAS_PREREQUISITE.PREREQUISITEID%TYPE,

DID   IN DEPARTMENT.DEPTID%TYPE
)

IS

CONDITION1 NUMBER;

CONDITION2 NUMBER;

WRONG_PREQ EXCEPTION;

BEGIN
  /* this can be checked before any SQL */

IF (SUBSTR(CID,5,3) <= SUBSTR(PID,5,3)) THEN /*PREREQUISITE HAS A HIGHER ID

THAN COURSEID */

RAISE WRONG_PREQ;

END IF;

SELECT COUNT(COURSEID)

INTO CONDITION1

FROM  COURSE

WHERE COURSEID = PID;

/* this can be checked here, without running the second select */

IF (CONDITION1 <>1)  THEN /*VIOLATION OF CONDITION 1, NO EXISTING 
                              PREREQUISITE COURSE*/

RAISE WRONG_PREQ;

END IF;

SELECT COUNT(*)

INTO CONDITION2

FROM HAS_PREREQUISITE

WHERE COURSEID = CID

AND PREREQUISITEID = PID

AND SUBSTR(CID,5,3) > SUBSTR(PID,5,3);

IF (CONDITION2 = 1) THEN /*THE RECORD ALREADYS EXISTS IN HAS_PREREQUISITE 
                             TABLE*/

RAISE WRONG_PREQ;

END IF;

INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES(CID,CNAME,'NULL','NULL' );

INSERT INTO HAS_PREREQUISITE VALUES(CID,PID);

INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (DEPTID,'NULL');

EXCEPTION

WHEN WRONG_PREQ THEN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COURSEID OR PREREQUISITE ID IS INVALID');

END NEW_COURSE;

This is done is Oracle SQL Developer.

DDL

/*==============================================================*/

/* DBMS name:      ORACLE Version 11g                           */

/* Created on:     11/10/2016 3:47:29 PM                        */

/*==============================================================*/

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   drop constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_STUDENT;

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   drop constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_COURSE;

alter table COURSE
   drop constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME;

alter table ENROLS
   drop constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS_STUDENT;

alter table ENROLS
   drop constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS2_TUT_PRAC;

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   drop constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE;

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   drop constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE;

alter table STAFF
   drop constraint FK_STAFF_RELATIONS_DEPARTME;

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   drop constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_STAFF;

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   drop constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE;

alter table TUT_PRAC
   drop constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_HAS_COURSE;

alter table TUT_PRAC
   drop constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_RELATIONS_STAFF;

drop table ACADEMIC_REC  cascade constraints;

drop table COURSE cascade constraints;

drop table ENROLS cascade constraints;

drop table HAS_PREREQUISITE cascade constraints;

drop table STAFF cascade constraints;

drop table STUDENT cascade constraints;

drop table TEACHING_INFORMATION cascade constraints;

drop table TUT_PRAC cascade constraints;

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: ACADEMIC_REC                                          */

/*==============================================================*/

create table ACADEMIC_REC

(

STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

STATUS               VARCHAR2(5),

YEAR                 NUMBER(4),

SEMESTER             CHAR(2),

GRADE                VARCHAR2(2)

constraint CKC_GRADE_ACADEMIC check (GRADE is null or (GRADE in

('HD','D','CR','P','F'))),

constraint PK_ACADEMIC_REC primary key (STUID, COURSEID)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: COURSE                                                */

/*==============================================================*/

create table COURSE

(

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSENAME           VARCHAR2(20),

TEXTBOOK             VARCHAR2(20),

CREDITHOUR           NUMBER(2),

MAX_ENROL            NUMBER(4),

ACTUAL_ENROL         NUMBER(4),

AVAILABILITY         NUMBER(4),

COURSE_TIME          CHAR(7),

constraint PK_COURSE primary key (COURSEID)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: DEPARTMENT                                            */

/*==============================================================*/

create table DEPARTMENT 
(

DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,

DEPTNAME             VARCHAR2(20),

DEPTCONTACTNO        NUMBER(10),

BUILDING             VARCHAR2(5),

constraint PK_DEPARTMENT primary key (DEPTID)

);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: ENROLS                                                */

/*==============================================================*/

create table ENROLS 
(

STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,

CLASSID              CHAR(8)              not null,

constraint PK_ENROLS primary key (STUID, CLASSID)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: HAS_PREREQUISITE                                      */

/*==============================================================*/

create table HAS_PREREQUISITE 
(

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

PREREQUISITEID       CHAR(8)              not null,

constraint PK_HAS_PREREQUISITE primary key (COURSEID, PREREQUISITEID)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: STAFF                                                 */

/*==============================================================*/

create table STAFF 
(

STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,

DEPARTMENTID         CHAR(8)              not null,

STAFFNAME            VARCHAR2(50),

STAFFADDRESS         VARCHAR2(70),

STAFFCONTACTNO       NUMBER(10),

STAFFEMAIL           VARCHAR2(50),

OFFICENO             NUMBER(5),

ROLE                 VARCHAR2(10),

constraint PK_STAFF primary key (STAFFID)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: STUDENT                                               */

/*==============================================================*/

create table STUDENT 
(

STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,

DEGREE               VARCHAR2(10),

MAJOR                VARCHAR2(10),

STU_NAME             VARCHAR2(50),

STU_ADDRESS          VARCHAR2(70),

CONTACTNO            NUMBER(10),

EMAIL                VARCHAR2(50),

constraint PK_STUDENT primary key (STUID)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: TEACHING_INFORMATION                                  */

/*==============================================================*/

create table TEACHING_INFORMATION 
(

STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

SEMESTER             CHAR(2)              not null,

YEAR                 NUMBER(4)            not null,

constraint PK_TEACHING_INFORMATION primary key (STAFFID, COURSEID, SEMESTER, YEAR)
);

/*==============================================================*/

/* Table: TUT_PRAC                                              */

/*==============================================================*/

create table TUT_PRAC 
(

CLASSID              CHAR(8)              not null,

COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,

STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,

TYPE                 VARCHAR2(5),

DAY                  VARCHAR2(10),

TIME                 DATE,

ROOMID               CHAR(10),

NO_OF_SEATS          NUMBER(2),

constraint PK_TUT_PRAC primary key (CLASSID)
);

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   add constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_STUDENT foreign key (STUID)
      references STUDENT (STUID);

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   add constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table COURSE
   add constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

alter table ENROLS
   add constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS_STUDENT foreign key (STUID)
      references STUDENT (STUID);

alter table ENROLS
   add constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS2_TUT_PRAC foreign key (CLASSID)
      references TUT_PRAC (CLASSID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (PREREQUISITEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table STAFF
   add constraint FK_STAFF_RELATIONS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPARTMENTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   add constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_STAFF foreign key (STAFFID)
      references STAFF (STAFFID);

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   add constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table TUT_PRAC
   add constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_HAS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table TUT_PRAC

add constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_RELATIONS_STAFF foreign key (STAFFID)
      references STAFF (STAFFID);

Comment: Please post your table structures. Also, trust the error messages: for example, if it's saying "not enough values" you are probably inserting a row with 3 columns in a table with more than 3 columns

Comment: alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

Comment: alter table COURSE
   add constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

Comment: Please edit your question, do not add comments. Also, in `HAS_PREREQUISITE` you are inserting 4 values, but it only has 2 columns... check your tables and your `insert` statements

Comment: I think inserting 'NULL' as string is a bad idea. Better use literal `NULL`.

Comment: Comments are like this `/* VIOLATION OF CONDITION 1 */` (or else everything to the right of `--`). You've used `/` around comments in a couple of places. Also please post code formatted and indented (and ideally not in block capitals).

Comment: Also the exception handling isn't helpful. If any of three different validation checks fail, you print an uninformative debug message and then exit the procedure successfully. In a production system nobody would even see the debug message, so your procedure would just complete instantly and the users would be left wondering why no rows were inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have clear error message. All regarding following tables:

The first table say `not enough values`. It means you try insert less values than columns in table

```
INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES(CID,CNAME,'NULL','NULL' );
-- Error(29,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(29,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values 
You may add values or specify a columns for instance `INSERT INTO COURSE (course_id, course_name, val1, val2 ) VALUES(CID,CNAME,'NULL','NULL' );`
```

Next;

```
INSERT INTO HAS_PREREQUISITE VALUES(CID,PID,'NULL','NULL');
-- Error(30,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(30,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
```

Its clear too. table HAS_PREREQUISITE has less columns then you try to insert. Delete extra values

```
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (DEPTID,'NULL');
-- Error(31,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(31,15): PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Is the same as first example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to edit your code moving some checks around to avoid unuseful queries and showing you what to edit; follow the comments:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE NEW_COURSE (
  CID   IN COURSE.COURSEID%TYPE, 
  CNAME IN COURSE.COURSENAME%TYPE,
  PID   IN HAS_PREREQUISITE.PREREQUISITEID%TYPE,
  DID   IN DEPARTMENT.DEPTID%TYPE
)
IS 
  CONDITION1 NUMBER;
  CONDITION2 NUMBER;
  WRONG_PREQ EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  /* this can be checked before any SQL */
  IF (SUBSTR(CID,5,3) <= SUBSTR(PID,5,3)) THEN /*PREREQUISITE HAS A HIGHER ID THAN COURSEID */
    RAISE WRONG_PREQ;
  END IF;



  SELECT COUNT(COURSEID) 
    INTO CONDITION1
    FROM  COURSE 
   WHERE COURSEID = PID;

  /* this can be checked here, without running the second select */
  IF (CONDITION1 <>1)  THEN /*VIOLATION OF CONDITION 1, NO EXISTING 
                              PREREQUISITE COURSE*/
    RAISE WRONG_PREQ;
  END IF; 


  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO CONDITION2
    FROM HAS_PREREQUISITE
   WHERE COURSEID = CID 
     AND PREREQUISITEID = PID 
     AND SUBSTR(CID,5,3) > SUBSTR(PID,5,3);

  IF (CONDITION2 = 1) THEN /*THE RECORD ALREADYS EXISTS IN HAS_PREREQUISITE 
                             TABLE*/
    RAISE WRONG_PREQ;
  END IF;



  INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES(CID,CNAME,'NULL','NULL' );  /* edit the statement to fit the table structure  also 'NULL' or null ?*/
  INSERT INTO HAS_PREREQUISITE VALUES(CID,PID);         /* the table only has 2 colums */
  INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (DEPTID,'NULL');        /* edit the statement to fit the table structure. also 'NULL' or null ? */
EXCEPTION
  WHEN WRONG_PREQ THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COURSEID OR PREREQUISITE ID IS INVALID');
END NEW_COURSE;
```

Comment: the selects are conditions that has to be done before the procedure of entering new course can take place

Comment: Error(31,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
Error(31,59): PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: but this is what i get at line EXCEPTION

Comment: I simply moved the select around to check errors as they can be checked. For example, if the input parameters are wrong, why run queries?

Comment: everything is the same except i changed the insert statements

Comment: INSERT INTO COURSE(COURSEID,COURSENAME,VAL1,VAL2) VALUES(CID,CNAME,'NULL','NULL' );
  INSERT INTO HAS_PREREQUISITE(COURSEID,PREREQUISITEID,VAL1,VAL2) VALUES(CID,PID,'NULL','NULL');
  INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT(DEPTID,VAL1) VALUES (DID,'NULL')

Comment: missing a semicolon after the last insert? Also, as said, edit the question instead of posting code in comments. I modified the insert into HAS_PREREQUISITE in my answer.. why did you change it? The table only has TWO columns and you're inserting FOUR value

Comment: I can't try the code without the table structure; please post the CREATE TABLE statements of the involved table