# NEW_COURSE pl/sql procedure is raising exception and i cant figure it out

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

The course procedure is supposed to :

1. The prerequisite courses for it (if any) already exist in the COURSE table. For simplicity,
   we will pretend that a course can have at most one course as prerequisite.
2. The prerequisite for a course must be at a lower level. For instance, the prerequisite for
   ISYS326 must be a100- or 200-level course, and cannot be a 300 level course.
3. If either of the above requirements fails, the procedure raises an exception WRONG_PREREQ
   that prints an appropriate alert message, and does not modify the COURSE table.

so i have done the procedure as mentioned:

```html
create or replace PROCEDURE NEW_COURSE (
  CID   IN COURSE.COURSEID%TYPE, 
  CNAME IN COURSE.COURSENAME%TYPE,
  PID   IN HAS_PREREQUISITE.PREREQUISITEID%TYPE,
  DID   IN DEPARTMENT.DEPTID%TYPE
)
IS 
  CONDITION1 NUMBER;
  CONDITION2 NUMBER;
  WRONG_PREQ EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  /* this can be checked before any SQL */
  IF (SUBSTR(CID,5,3) <= SUBSTR(PID,5,3)) THEN /*PREREQUISITE HAS A HIGHER ID THAN COURSEID */
    RAISE WRONG_PREQ;
  END IF;



  SELECT COUNT(COURSEID) 
    INTO CONDITION1
    FROM  COURSE 
   WHERE COURSEID = PID;

  /* this can be checked here, without running the second select */
  IF (CONDITION1 <>1)  THEN /*VIOLATION OF CONDITION 1, NO EXISTING 
                              PREREQUISITE COURSE*/
    RAISE WRONG_PREQ;
  END IF; 


  SELECT COUNT(*)
    INTO CONDITION2
    FROM HAS_PREREQUISITE
   WHERE COURSEID = CID 
     AND PREREQUISITEID = PID 
     AND SUBSTR(CID,5,3) > SUBSTR(PID,5,3);

  IF (CONDITION2 = 1) THEN /*THE RECORD ALREADYS EXISTS IN HAS_PREREQUISITE 
                             TABLE*/
    RAISE WRONG_PREQ;
  END IF;



  INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES(CID,CNAME,DID,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);  /* edit the statement to fit the table structure  also 'NULL' or null ?*/
  INSERT INTO HAS_PREREQUISITE VALUES(CID,PID);         /* the table only has 2 colums */
  INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (DID,NULL,NULL,NULL);        /* edit the statement to fit the table structure. also 'NULL' or null ? */
EXCEPTION
  WHEN WRONG_PREQ THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('COURSEID OR PREREQUISITE ID IS INVALID');
END NEW_COURSE;
```

And when i tried to call the procedure through anonymous block like this

```html
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
CID char(8):='isys228';
CNAME varchar2(20):='Greendata';
PID char(8):='isys114';
DID char(8):='comp3647';
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The course has been enrolled');
NEW_COURSE(CNAME,CID,PID,DID);
END;
/
```

UPDATE: the anonymous block works but i cant see the data entered in the table

And i was trying to Open a new course ISYS228, “Green Data”, with ISYS114 as prerequisite, through this procedure.

PLEASE HELP!! I'm fairly new to this sql so i have difficulty seeing where im going wrong

just incase heres the ddl

```html
/*==============================================================*/
/* DBMS name:      ORACLE Version 11g                           */
/* Created on:     11/10/2016 3:47:29 PM                        */
/*==============================================================*/


alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   drop constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_STUDENT;

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   drop constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_COURSE;

alter table COURSE
   drop constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME;

alter table ENROLS
   drop constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS_STUDENT;

alter table ENROLS
   drop constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS2_TUT_PRAC;

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   drop constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE;

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   drop constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE;

alter table STAFF
   drop constraint FK_STAFF_RELATIONS_DEPARTME;

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   drop constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_STAFF;

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   drop constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE;

alter table TUT_PRAC
   drop constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_HAS_COURSE;

alter table TUT_PRAC
   drop constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_RELATIONS_STAFF;

drop table ACADEMIC_REC  cascade constraints;

drop table COURSE cascade constraints;

drop table ENROLS cascade constraints;

drop table HAS_PREREQUISITE cascade constraints;

drop table STAFF cascade constraints;

drop table STUDENT cascade constraints;

drop table TEACHING_INFORMATION cascade constraints;

drop table TUT_PRAC cascade constraints;

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: ACADEMIC_REC                                          */
/*==============================================================*/
create table ACADEMIC_REC 
(
   STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   STATUS               VARCHAR2(5),
   YEAR                 NUMBER(4),
   SEMESTER             CHAR(2),
   GRADE                VARCHAR2(2)         
      constraint CKC_GRADE_ACADEMIC check (GRADE is null or (GRADE in ('HD','D','CR','P','F'))),
   constraint PK_ACADEMIC_REC primary key (STUID, COURSEID)
);


/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: COURSE                                                */
/*==============================================================*/
create table COURSE 
(
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,
   COURSENAME           VARCHAR2(20),
   TEXTBOOK             VARCHAR2(20),
   CREDITHOUR           NUMBER(2),
   MAX_ENROL            NUMBER(4),
   ACTUAL_ENROL         NUMBER(4),
   AVAILABILITY         NUMBER(4),
   COURSE_TIME          CHAR(7),
   constraint PK_COURSE primary key (COURSEID)
);


/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: DEPARTMENT                                            */
/*==============================================================*/
create table DEPARTMENT 
(
   DEPTID               CHAR(8)              not null,
   DEPTNAME             VARCHAR2(20),
   DEPTCONTACTNO        NUMBER(10),
   BUILDING             VARCHAR2(5),
   constraint PK_DEPARTMENT primary key (DEPTID)
);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: ENROLS                                                */
/*==============================================================*/
create table ENROLS 
(
   STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,
   CLASSID              CHAR(8)              not null,
   constraint PK_ENROLS primary key (STUID, CLASSID)
);


/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: HAS_PREREQUISITE                                      */
/*==============================================================*/
create table HAS_PREREQUISITE 
(
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   PREREQUISITEID       CHAR(8)              not null,
   constraint PK_HAS_PREREQUISITE primary key (COURSEID, PREREQUISITEID)
);


/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: STAFF                                                 */
/*==============================================================*/
create table STAFF 
(
   STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,
   DEPARTMENTID         CHAR(8)              not null,
   STAFFNAME            VARCHAR2(50),
   STAFFADDRESS         VARCHAR2(70),
   STAFFCONTACTNO       NUMBER(10),
   STAFFEMAIL           VARCHAR2(50),
   OFFICENO             NUMBER(5),
   ROLE                 VARCHAR2(10),
   constraint PK_STAFF primary key (STAFFID)
);


/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: STUDENT                                               */
/*==============================================================*/
create table STUDENT 
(
   STUID                CHAR(8)              not null,
   DEGREE               VARCHAR2(10),
   MAJOR                VARCHAR2(10),
   STU_NAME             VARCHAR2(50),
   STU_ADDRESS          VARCHAR2(70),
   CONTACTNO            NUMBER(10),
   EMAIL                VARCHAR2(50),
   constraint PK_STUDENT primary key (STUID)
);

/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: TEACHING_INFORMATION                                  */
/*==============================================================*/
create table TEACHING_INFORMATION 
(
   STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   SEMESTER             CHAR(2)              not null,
   YEAR                 NUMBER(4)            not null,
   constraint PK_TEACHING_INFORMATION primary key (STAFFID, COURSEID, SEMESTER, YEAR)
);


/*==============================================================*/
/* Table: TUT_PRAC                                              */
/*==============================================================*/
create table TUT_PRAC 
(
   CLASSID              CHAR(8)              not null,
   COURSEID             CHAR(8)              not null,
   STAFFID              CHAR(8)              not null,
   TYPE                 VARCHAR2(5),
   DAY                  VARCHAR2(10),
   TIME                 DATE,
   ROOMID               CHAR(10),
   NO_OF_SEATS          NUMBER(2),
   constraint PK_TUT_PRAC primary key (CLASSID)
);


alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   add constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_STUDENT foreign key (STUID)
      references STUDENT (STUID);

alter table ACADEMIC_REC
   add constraint FK_ACADEMIC_RELATIONS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table COURSE
   add constraint FK_COURSE_OFFERS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

alter table ENROLS
   add constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS_STUDENT foreign key (STUID)
      references STUDENT (STUID);

alter table ENROLS
   add constraint FK_ENROLS_ENROLS2_TUT_PRAC foreign key (CLASSID)
      references TUT_PRAC (CLASSID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table HAS_PREREQUISITE
   add constraint FK_HAS_PRER_HAS_PRERE_COURSE foreign key (PREREQUISITEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table STAFF
   add constraint FK_STAFF_RELATIONS_DEPARTME foreign key (DEPARTMENTID)
      references DEPARTMENT (DEPTID);

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   add constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_STAFF foreign key (STAFFID)
      references STAFF (STAFFID);

alter table TEACHING_INFORMATION
   add constraint FK_TEACHING_RELATIONS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table TUT_PRAC
   add constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_HAS_COURSE foreign key (COURSEID)
      references COURSE (COURSEID);

alter table TUT_PRAC
   add constraint FK_TUT_PRAC_RELATIONS_STAFF foreign key (STAFFID)
      references STAFF (STAFFID);
```

Comment: Is it same as your question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233768/i-keep-getting-errors-in-my-procedure-that-help-add-new-course-and-i-have-put-re)? And you should check this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40353416/sql-procedures-comparing-values#comment67962225_40353416), I think you 2 are classmate...

Comment: i dont think so, even if it sounds same. sorry but do you have any idea where's the glitch?

Answer (score 0):

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
CID char(8):='isys228';
CNAME varchar2(20):='Greendata';
PID char(8):='isys114';
DID char(8):='comp3647';
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The course has been enrolled');
END;
```

Try that instead

Comment: it works but i dont see the data in the table, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

1. what error message are you getting?
2. try to use this code.

   ```
   SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
   DECLARE
   CID COURSE.COURSEID%TYPE:='isys228';
   CNAME COURSE.COURSENAME%TYPE:='Greendata';
   PID HAS_PREREQUISITE.PREREQUISITEID%TYPE:='isys114';
   DID DEPARTMENT.DEPTID%TYPE:='comp3647';
   BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('The course has been enrolled');
   NEW_COURSE(CNAME,CID,PID,DID);
   END;
   /
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your inserts.
Try putting

```
commit;
```

after

```
NEW_COURSE(CNAME,CID,PID,DID);
```

Or if you want to commit in the Procedure

```
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (DID,NULL,NULL,NULL);        /* edit the statement to fit the table structure. also 'NULL' or null ? */
COMMIT;
```

EDIT
Reorder your insert orders since COURSE has an FK to DEPARTMENT

```
-- FIRST THE INSERT IN DEPARTMENT
INSERT INTO DEPARTMENT VALUES (DID,NULL,NULL,NULL);        /* edit the statement to fit the table structure. also 'NULL' or null ? */

 INSERT INTO COURSE VALUES(CID,CNAME,DID,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL);  /*     edit the statement to fit the table structure  also 'NULL' or null ?*/

 INSERT INTO HAS_PREREQUISITE VALUES(CID,PID);         /* the table only has 2 colums */
```

Comment: Try to exec the inserts with the values and see what happens

Comment: See the EDIT in my answer, you should move the insert into department at the beginnning

Comment: Please execute manually the 3 inserts in an sqlplus session and report the (possible) error message